# JavaScript - Get the value of a variable generated inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the value of a variable generated inside a forEach loop outside of it, please look at the code snippet:

```
  var variable = "";

  array.forEach(el=>{
  variable =  el.checkStatus;
  })

  //How to get the value of variable here ?
```

Comment: Simply by saying `return variable`

Comment: `variable` will contain the value of the last array element. Perhaps that's what is bothering you? You can access any element of `array` by writing `array[index].checkStatus`

Comment: Uh... what?  The return form the callback has no documented effect, and `variable` will contain the value of the last array element *without* any return statement.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Correct, Corrado changed his/her previously correct comment after my reply

Comment: @le_m correct, using the current code I have I am getting only the last array element. For your suggested method to work, I believe that I need to have `array.forEach(el,index)` right ?

Comment: @Folky.H You want to get not only the last element's status but *all* statuses? Then check out @Morleee's answer below using `map`.

Comment: @Folky.H You get the last one because you keep overwriting the variable. Did you expect it to concatenate all of them somehow? What are you expecting to see when you check the variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
  var statuses = array.map(el => {
    return el.checkStatus;
  })
```

Then simply call statuses[index] depending on the status you want

Comment: @le_m : Simpler, maybe, but wouldn't accomplish what OP asked for.  This answer does what OP is apparently trying to do (albeit not using implementation specifics OP called for, so may or may not apply to their real use case)

Comment: Depends on the use case, looks like OP wants to access all of the arrays status'

Comment: In this case, again to call `statuses[index]` I need to run a for loop ! So I'll be back to the starting point

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Well, what OP asked for is a non-problem so there's nothing to accomplish in that case. The question was *how to have a variable that get its value assigned function available outside that function* and the answer to that question is: "It already is!"

Comment: @Folky.H Just what are you trying to do? You're being very unclear. What value do you expect the variable to have in the end?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm - I considered that, but OP asked a question for a reason, so I would assume it's a matter of lack of clarity, rather than a non-problem.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Obviously yes, I was simply referring to your comment about how this answer didn't accomplish "what OP asked for". Since OP still hasn't clarified what he's asking for, this seems like a very good answer to what he's most likely trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You could make `variable` an array of each elements `checkStatus` values.

```
var variable = new Array();

array.forEach(el => {
    variable.push(el.checkStatus());
})
```

This would be more elegantly done using an array `map` function though.

```
var variable = array.map(el => el.checkStatus())
```